# XSLT to extract values

Tags: xml, wcf, xslt, xml-namespaces

We have an application. The webservices in the application are based on WCF.

Please see below the response xml that I am getting from the application. I am struggling to figure out how to extract certain values from the application. There are so many inline xmlns declarations.

Here's the input xml that I am getting from the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RequestSelectionValuesResponse xmlns="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/WSShopFloor" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RequestSelectionValuesResult>true</RequestSelectionValuesResult>
    <serviceInfo xmlns:q3="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/DataTypes" q3:type="OnlineQuery_Info">
      <OnlineQuerySelection>
        <RequestValue>false</RequestValue>
        <RequestMetadata>false</RequestMetadata>
        <RequestSubFieldValues>false</RequestSubFieldValues>
        <RequestSelectionValues>true</RequestSelectionValues>
        <SelectionValuesInput/>
        <SelectionValues>
          <RecordSetHeader>
            <ColumnCount>12</ColumnCount>
            <ColumnHeaders>
              <__listItem>
                <Name>No</Name>
                <FieldType>
                  <GenericType>Float</GenericType>
                  <SpecificType/>
                  <ReferenceType/>
                  <IsList>false</IsList>
                </FieldType>
                <Label>
                  <Id>0</Id>
                  <Name/>
                  <DefaultValue/>
                  <Value/>
                </Label>
              </__listItem>
              <__listItem>
                <Name>LotId</Name>
                <FieldType>
                  <GenericType>String</GenericType>
                  <SpecificType/>
                  <ReferenceType/>
                  <IsList>false</IsList>
                </FieldType>
                <Label>
                  <Id>0</Id>
                  <Name/>
                  <DefaultValue/>
                  <Value/>
                </Label>
              </__listItem>
              <__listItem>
                <Name>VendorCommitDate</Name>
                <FieldType>    
                  <GenericType>String</GenericType>
                  <SpecificType/>
                  <ReferenceType/>
                  <IsList>false</IsList>
                </FieldType>
                <Label>
                  <Id>0</Id>
                  <Name/>
                  <DefaultValue/>
                  <Value/>
                </Label>
              </__listItem>
              <__listItem>
                <Name>Operation</Name>
                <FieldType>
                  <GenericType>String</GenericType>
                  <SpecificType/>
                  <ReferenceType/>
                  <IsList>false</IsList>
                </FieldType>
                <Label>
                  <Id>0</Id>
                  <Name/>
                  <DefaultValue/>
                  <Value/>
                </Label>
              </__listItem>
              <__listItem>
                <Name>ProcessCode</Name>
                <FieldType>                         
                  <GenericType>String</GenericType>
                  <SpecificType/>
                  <ReferenceType/>
                  <IsList>false</IsList>
                </FieldType>
                <Label>
                  <Id>0</Id>
                  <Name/>
                  <DefaultValue/>
                  <Value/>
                </Label>
              </__listItem>
              <__listItem>
                <Name>DieQty</Name>
                <FieldType>
                  <GenericType>Float</GenericType>
                  <SpecificType/>
                  <ReferenceType/>
                  <IsList>false</IsList>
                </FieldType>
                <Label>
                  <Id>0</Id>
                  <Name/>
                  <DefaultValue/>
                  <Value/>
                </Label>
              </__listItem>
              <__listItem>
                <Name>WaferQty</Name>
                <FieldType>
                  <GenericType>Float</GenericType>
                  <SpecificType/>
                  <ReferenceType/>
                  <IsList>false</IsList>
                </FieldType>
                <Label>
                  <Id>0</Id>
                  <Name/>
                  <DefaultValue/>
                  <Value/>
                </Label>
              </__listItem>
              <__listItem>
                <Name>HardwareProductid</Name>
                <FieldType>
                  <GenericType>String</GenericType>
                  <SpecificType/>
                  <ReferenceType/>
                  <IsList>false</IsList>
                </FieldType>
                <Label>
                  <Id>0</Id>
                  <Name/>
                  <DefaultValue/>
                  <Value/>
                </Label>
              </__listItem>
              <__listItem>
                <Name>NoOfLot</Name>
                <FieldType>
                  <GenericType>Float</GenericType>
                  <SpecificType/>
                  <ReferenceType/>
                  <IsList>false</IsList>
                </FieldType>
                <Label>
                  <Id>0</Id>
                  <Name/>
                  <DefaultValue/>
                  <Value/>
                </Label>
              </__listItem>
              <__listItem>
                <Name>Status</Name>
                <FieldType>
                  <GenericType>String</GenericType>
                  <SpecificType/>
                  <ReferenceType/>
                  <IsList>false</IsList>
                </FieldType>
                <Label>
                  <Id>0</Id>
                  <Name/>
                  <DefaultValue/>
                  <Value/>
                </Label>
              </__listItem>
              <__listItem>
                <Name>InQueue</Name>
                <FieldType>
                  <GenericType>String</GenericType>
                  <SpecificType/>
                  <ReferenceType/>
                  <IsList>false</IsList>
                </FieldType>
                <Label>
                  <Id>0</Id>
                  <Name/>
                  <DefaultValue/>
                  <Value/>
                </Label>
              </__listItem>
              <__listItem>
                <Name>Multiple_Lot_Matched</Name>
                <FieldType>
                  <GenericType>String</GenericType>
                  <SpecificType/>
                  <ReferenceType/>
                  <IsList>false</IsList>
                </FieldType>
                <Label>
                  <Id>0</Id>
                  <Name/>
                  <DefaultValue/>
                  <Value/>
                </Label>
              </__listItem>
            </ColumnHeaders>
          </RecordSetHeader>
          <Data>
            <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
              <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msdata:EnforceConstraints="False">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="Table1">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="No" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="LotId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="VendorCommitDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="Operation" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="ProcessCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="DieQty" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="WaferQty" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="HardwareProductid" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="NoOfLot" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="InQueue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="Multiple_Lot_Matched" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:choice>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
              <NewDataSet xmlns="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/DataTypes">
                <Table1 diffgr:id="Table11" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                  <No>1</No>
                  <LotId>5000018</LotId>
                  <VendorCommitDate>07-31-2013</VendorCommitDate>
                  <Operation>SORT</Operation>
                  <ProcessCode>SO</ProcessCode>
                  <DieQty>2500</DieQty>
                  <WaferQty>25</WaferQty>
                  <HardwareProductid>Hardware_Prod_for_5000018</HardwareProductid>
                  <NoOfLot>2</NoOfLot>
                  <Status>OPEN</Status>
                  <InQueue>NO</InQueue>
                  <Multiple_Lot_Matched>TRUE</Multiple_Lot_Matched>
                </Table1>
                <Table1 diffgr:id="Table12" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                  <No>2</No>
                  <LotId>5000019</LotId>
                  <VendorCommitDate>08-31-2013</VendorCommitDate>
                  <Operation>SORT</Operation>
                  <ProcessCode>SO</ProcessCode>
                  <DieQty>50000</DieQty>
                  <WaferQty>25</WaferQty>
                  <HardwareProductid>Hardware_Prod_for_5000019</HardwareProductid>
                  <NoOfLot>2</NoOfLot>
                  <Status>OPEN</Status>
                  <InQueue>YES</InQueue>
                  <Multiple_Lot_Matched>TRUE</Multiple_Lot_Matched>
                </Table1>
              </NewDataSet>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
          </Data>
        </SelectionValues>
      </OnlineQuerySelection>
    </serviceInfo>
    <resultStatus xmlns:q1="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/DataTypes" xsi:type="q1:ResultStatus">
      <Message xmlns="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/DataTypes">Update completed successfully</Message>
      <IsError xmlns="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/DataTypes">false</IsError>
    </resultStatus>
  </RequestSelectionValuesResponse>
```

From the above XML I need to extract these values (all the values under Table1):

```
<Table1 diffgr:id="Table11" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
  <No>1</No>
  <LotId>5000018</LotId>
  <VendorCommitDate>07-31-2013</VendorCommitDate>
  <Operation>SORT</Operation>
  <ProcessCode>SO</ProcessCode>
  <DieQty>2500</DieQty>
  <WaferQty>25</WaferQty>
  <HardwareProductid>Hardware_Prod_for_5000018</HardwareProductid>
  <NoOfLot>2</NoOfLot>
  <Status>OPEN</Status>
  <InQueue>NO</InQueue>
  <Multiple_Lot_Matched>TRUE</Multiple_Lot_Matched>
</Table1>
<Table1 diffgr:id="Table12" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
  <No>2</No>
  <LotId>5000019</LotId>
  <VendorCommitDate>08-31-2013</VendorCommitDate>
  <Operation>SORT</Operation>
  <ProcessCode>SO</ProcessCode>
  <DieQty>50000</DieQty>
  <WaferQty>25</WaferQty>
  <HardwareProductid>Hardware_Prod_for_5000019</HardwareProductid>
  <NoOfLot>2</NoOfLot>
  <Status>OPEN</Status>
  <InQueue>YES</InQueue>
  <Multiple_Lot_Matched>TRUE</Multiple_Lot_Matched>
</Table1>
```

How to go about this? Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You could extract the values quite easily with LINQ to XML.  However, there's a much bigger problem from my point of view - that hideously long XML you posted looks suspiciously like a `DataSet` that's been serialized.  One of the WCF best practices is to **NOT** use `DataSet`s and other .NET-specific constructs (as non-.NET clients won't know how to consume/create them).  You'd be much better off to write a simple class that has those values and apply the `[DataContract]` attribute to them for passing the data back forth, and save yourself a lot of headaches down the road.

Comment: When you say 'extract', do you want to just dump out the contents?   I'm wondering if your query is an xpath query rather than xslt?

Comment: @Tim - I think you are probably right but I dont have a choice. I am working in Oracle SOA Suite transformation so have to use XSLT. Not sure if there's any other way.

Comment: @Fiona - Even if I can copy the whole structure underneath the Table1 that will do my job. In the end I need a structured XML output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you would like to extract it. Following is a solution using XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:d="http://www.camstar.com/WebService/DataTypes">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//d:NewDataSet/d:Table1">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the xslt. It's extracting all the value. Is there way I can copy the whole structure underneath the Table1 tag? I can then easily map it to other structure.

Comment: What do you mean by 'copy the whole structure underneath'? The above xslt is copying the Table1 already. What's the output you're expecting?

Comment: Whereas I am trying to get:           <No>1</No>
          <LotId>5000018</LotId>
          <VendorCommitDate>07-31-2013</VendorCommitDate>
          <Operation>SORT</Operation>
          <ProcessCode>SO</ProcessCode>
          <DieQty>2500</DieQty>
          <WaferQty>25</WaferQty>
          <HardwareProductid>Hardware_Prod_for_5000018</HardwareProductid>
          <NoOfLot>2</NoOfLot>
          <Status>OPEN</Status>
          <InQueue>NO</InQueue>
          <Multiple_Lot_Matched>TRUE</Multiple_Lot_Matched>